# How to convert/transform a collection to another collection by element's property?

Tags: collections, filter, kotlin

If I have a collection of an object in Kotlin, is there a quick way to get a collection of a certain property of those objects? I looked at a list of [collection operations for Kotlin](https://antonioleiva.com/collection-operations-kotlin/), but nothing stood out for me (but I may have overlooked something)

In python it would be akin to:

`[person.name for person in persons]`

And I'd prefer to use a collections function instead of doing:

```
var nameMap = mutableListOf<String>()
persons.forEach{person -> nameMap.add(person.name)}
```

I'm pretty lacking in knowledge of filtering/lambda functions and anything other than list comprehension, so apologies if this is a simple question

Answer (score 124, accepted):

it's easy to do in Kotlin:

```
//           v--- the variable type can be removed
var nameMap: MutableList<String> = persons.map { it.name }.toMutableList();
```

**IF** you want an immutable `List`, it can simplify as below:

```
//           v--- the variable type can be removed
var nameMap: List<String> = persons.map { it.name };
```

**OR** using [function reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) instead:

```
var nameMap = persons.map(Person::name);
```

Comment: Why mutable list?

Comment: @marstran because your question defined as `MutableList<String>`

Comment: It's not my question. Also, he didn't specify mutable list anywhere. He just used it in his workaround.

Comment: @marstran yeah. I see. the OP define the `MutableList<String>` in his question implicitly. I only make the variable type explicity let the OP know the actually type.

Comment: Didn't know about the function reference expression, thanks for the thorough answer! :)

Comment: @Parker you can see here in more details: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references .

Comment: @holi-java OP used a mutable list to add values to it via `forEach` function, it doesn't mean he actually needs one

Comment: @Pavlus hi, but he doesn't said he doesn't want to operates the **list**  as further. so I provide 2 list types.

Answer (score 58):

If you want to map model then do this.

```
var nameMap: List<Model> = persons.map { Model(it.name,it.number) };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

```
inline fun <reified T, Y> MutableList<T>.listOfField(property: KMutableProperty1<T, Y?>): MutableList<Y> {
    val yy = ArrayList<Y>()
    this.forEach { t: T ->
        yy.add(property.get(t) as Y)
    }
    return yy
}
```

Usage:

```
val serviceIds = services.listOfField(ServiceModel::id)
```

**Option 2:**

```
var serviceIds: MutableList<String> = services.map { it.id }.toMutableList()
```

**Option 3:**

Function Reference

```
var serviceIds = services.map(Person::id)
```