# How to get a List of Objects from a List

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, sublist

I have a class with two members,

```
class Class2(var obj2: SomeObject, var time: Long) {}
```

and I have in the main Class an object defined like this:

```
var obj: ArrayList<Class2> = arrayListOf()
```

now I've realized I need to work with an ArrayList formed only with the obj2 got from the object obj, it means:

```
 var subobj = ArrayList<SomeObject> //extracted from obj
```

I know I can get that with

```
until(i in 0..obj.size) {//etc}
```

But, is there any more practical way? (in Kotlin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert/transform a collection to another collection by element's property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738319/how-to-convert-transform-a-collection-to-another-collection-by-elements-propert)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you're trying to obtain a list containing not `Class2` objects but their values of `obj2`.  You could try using Kotlin's [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) function

```
var subobj = obj.map { it.obj2 }
```

This allows you to pass a transformation that will run on each of the items in the list.  Here, `it` just refers to the current item you're looking at in the `obj` list.  This just returns a list of the values of `obj2` for each item in `obj`.

Comment: ok, according to your suggestions I've tried this: var subobj: ArrayList<SomeObject> = obj.map { it.obj2 }.toMutableList()  as the link above but it is causing type mismatch ... there's no option like toArrayList() .. humm what can I do?

Comment: @JoeCoolman, you can change `ArrayList` to `MutableList` and use `toMutableList`. The main difference between `List` and `ArrayList` is that the last one can be modified.

Comment: Thanks you all ... I have to delete this post